# Need angular ui-router child state to call parent state function using controllerAs syntax

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I would like to know how to pass a parent state's function to a child using ui-router and controllerAs syntax so I could call on a function used by the parent.

An example would be I have a view with a list, when I click on the list it loads the details in a child state, upon updating the child, update/refresh the list using a function on the parent state.

I made a plunkr for it here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/rRkibROTrXhkFSCuzcSb?p=preview

```
  .state('home.users', {
url: '/users',
templateUrl: 'users.html',
controller: function() {
  this.users = [
    { id: 1, name: 'User1'},
    { id: 2, name: 'User2'},
    { id: 3, name: 'User3'}];

  this.lastUpdated = new Date();
  this.updateList= function() {
    this.lastUpdated = new Date();
  }
},
controllerAs: 'usersVm' })

.state('home.users.details', {
url: '/:id',
templateUrl: 'usersdetails.html',
controller: function() {
  this.user = { id: 1, name: 'Users1' };
  this.update = function() {
    // update parent scope list here
    // usersVm.updateList();
    // $scope.$parent.usersVm.updateList()
  }
},
controllerAs: 'usersDetailsVm'
```

});

To get the error I am stuck on: click on Home.users.details.1, click Save. I would like the save button to call the parent function that updates the parent list. I could not get it to work without using $scope everywhere (which I am trying to avoid).

Am I thinking about this wrong? Should I do it another way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $scope in this context is probably fine. Parents function should be stored in $scope.parent if I am not mistaken.

But you should not overuse it. Alternatively, you could create a service handling these updates.

Comment: Opted to use $scope (and $scope.$parent), I'm not sure how I would use a service to share a list between both states (ie; child state would update the list and parent scope is bound to that list and gets updated on $digest?)?

Comment: Service would store the list, and have function to update it and get it. Using DI in both controllers you would include this service.

Comment: Thanks, will do that!